# Get max(date) record per month for each subscriber_id. Returning no duplicate id's per month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table (with no indexes) that contains columns: `unique_id`, `subscriber_id`, `note`, `date_note_created (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am)`, `officer_making_note`. A `subscriber_id` can have multiple notes made by different officers per month.

I would like to efficiently create a view that holds the single last record per month for each `subscriber_id` where the note is like `'%some string%'`.

```
select * from 
(select subscriber_id, note, date_note_created, officer_making_note
from table
where user_id = v_sub_id
and date_note_created between to_date(v_monthstart, 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
and to_date(v_monthend, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
AND (LOWER (note) LIKE '%z%' 
or (note) LIKE '%a%'
or lower(note) like '%b%' 
or lower(note) like '%c%' 
or lower(note) like '%d%')
order by date_note_created desc)
where rownum = 1;
```

The code above shows what I've done to achieve this for one `subscriber_id` for one month without duplicates.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are using Oracle.  This gives you access to the analytic functions.

Since you are looking for multiple months and all subscribers, I have removed the restriction on month in the `where` clause and the subscriber id.  I also added a month identifier (as a string in "YYYY-MM" format):

```
select *
from (select subscriber_id, note, date_note_created, officer_making_note, to_char(date_note_created, 'YYYY-MM') as mon
             row_number() over (partition by subscriber_id, to_char(date_note_created, 'YYYY-MM')
                                order by date_note_created desc) as seqnum
      from table
      where /* user_id = v_sub_id and */
            /* date_note_created between to_date(v_monthstart, 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date(v_monthend, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND */
            (LOWER (note) LIKE '%z%' or (note) LIKE '%a%' or lower(note) like '%b%' or lower(note) like '%c%' or lower(note) like '%d%'
            )
     )
where seqnum = 1
```

To create a view, you would simply use a `create view as` statement.

Comment: Thanks this worked exactly how it should. I'll look more into those analytical functions in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `ROW_NUMBER` window function, something like this:

```
select *
from ( 
   select subscriber_id
        , note, date_note_created, officer_making_note
        , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY subscriber_id
                              ORDER BY date_note_created DESC) as rn
   from table
   where user_id = v_sub_id
      and date_note_created between to_date(v_monthstart, 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
      and to_date(v_monthend, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
      and (   lower(note) LIKE '%z%' 
           or lower(note) LIKE '%a%'
           or lower(note) like '%b%' 
           or lower(note) like '%c%' 
           or lower(note) like '%d%')
   )  xx
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sorry if the code i put in threw off your response. I did want to eliminate hard coding the sub_id and dates.

Comment: NP: Gordon's answer is better in any case (and more complete); I failed to read your question thoroughly.